# PowerShell script to get path of wav files

Tags: powershell

With below PowerShell script I am able to get Name, Size, DateCreated, Length of wav files from folder but I also want path of each files.

Please help me to update this code.

```bsh
$folder= 'C:\Users\r.shishodia\Desktop\2-8-2018\web'
$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($folder)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++) {
    $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
    if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}
$com.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
        DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
        Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\r.shishodia\Desktop\report.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: You're looking for `$_.FullName` (or `$_.DirectoryName` if you just want the path of the containing folder).

Comment: Hi Ansgar Wiechers thanks for the reply, i use Path =$_.FullName and also Path =$_.DirectoryName but i did not get any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
Get-ChildItem $folder | % {$_.FullName}
```

The `FullName` parameter will give you the path for each file.

If we try your approach, then -

If you take a look at `$com.Items()`, you will see there is already a `Path` property in it. So you can directly add that in your custom `PSObject` and export it via `CSV`.

```
$com.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
        DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
        Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
        Path = $_.Path
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\r.shishodia\Desktop\report.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Vivek/Mark i have used your code-Path = Get-ChildItem $folder | % {$_.FullName} and Path = (Get-ChildItem $folder).FullName and i received System.Object[] in path column

Comment: It is because you have more than one object in the result

Comment: @saransh Have a look at the solution now!

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thank you for your reply - much appreciated.Awesome it work like a charm.Perfect!!!! Thanks so much for your assistance.